# Rails AJAX form validation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Where is the best place to implement form validation for an AJAX form in rails when I'm not using a model for the form?  And how would I go about implementing it?

My form being submitted needs to check if an IP address exists and is valid **before** the methods in the controller are run.  If the IP is invalid, I'd like to let the user know via a `flash[:danger]` message.

**views/tools/forms/_ping.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag ping_tool_path(1), role: "form", class: "form-inline form_ip", name: "ping-form", method: "post", remote: true do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :ip, params[:ip], class: "form-control" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Ping", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

**views/tools/ping.js.erb**

```
$(".output").html("<%= j (@results) %>");
```

**controllers/tools_controller.rb**

```
def ping
    ping_host(params[:ip])
    save_host(params[:ip])

    # AJAX
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on how much time and how much scalable your application is or intends to be.

For a more scalable solution, I would use `active_interaction` gem, create a new interaction and put the validation on it.

here is the docs https://github.com/orgsync/active_interaction

If you want a easier solution you can always create a private method on the controller that validates the ip.

#### edited

```
    private

    require 'resolv'

    def valid_ip?(ip)
      case ip
      when Resolv::IPv4::Regex
        return true
      when Resolv::IPv6::Regex
        return true
      else
        return false
      end
    end
```

inspired  on this article http://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/08/28/ruby-ip-address-regex/

#### edit 2

linking both parts

#### in your controller

```
    def ping
        if valid_ip?(params[:ip])
          ping_host(params[:ip])
          save_host(params[:ip])
          render json: { message: "sucess" }
        else
          render json: { errors: "Invalid Ip" }, status: 422
        end
    end
```

#### javascript

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.form_ip').on('ajax:success',function(e, data, status, xhr){
          // success message
          alert("success");
        }).on('ajax:error',function(e, xhr, status, error){
          // errors handler
          var errors = $.parseJson(xhr.response_text).errors;
          alert(errors);
        });
      });
    </script>
```

source -> http://travisjeffery.com/b/2012/04/rendering-errors-in-json-with-rails/

And If you want to validate before the user submits too, take a look at html5 input pattern attribute http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: At this point, I'm looking for an easier solution, like creating the private method to validate the IP.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a solution that you can use to validate your ip address

Comment: Ok, so this can validate the IP, but how do I tie it back into doing validation on the form before submittal via AJAX?

Comment: edited again with the code to link the feature into your frontend